# Can raspberry Pi 3 and Lidar lite v3 connecting without resistor in circuit?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, lidar

I recently try to use Lidar Lite v3 with my Rpi 3, and it works with I2C communication. My wiring method is due to offical documentation. [Wiring picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC0Bi.png) **However, what I have learned before is that the gpio pin of RPI can only afford 3.3v working voltage.** My Question is that shouldn't I add the resistor in my circuit to prevent from breaking out the pins of my RPI ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @old_timer thx for reminding, cause I am new to this platform.